# How can I display a line at the center of the canvas in Picture Collage Maker Pro?

Tags: guides, picture-collage-maker-pro

I use [Picture Collage Maker Pro](https://www.pearlmountainsoft.com/picture-collage-maker) and would like to display a line at the center of the canvas. In Photoshop 23.5.1, I use `View` -> `Guide` -> `New Guide Layout`:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I display a line at the center of the canvas in Picture Collage Maker Pro?

Answer (score 1):

Googled the *exact* same question word for word..
found a YouTube tutorial.. after watching for 1 minute.... 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nnmug5JxT54

For Pic-collage, it seems that one can use the "Freestyle" setup,
then choose a "Grid" and select the grid with 2 columns.

---

For Photoshop you don't really need a "Guide Layout" ... 
just "New Guide" and enter `50%` in the measurement box and tick horizontal or vertical.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this is for a different application :( good to know about Photoshop!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt **Read** the *entire* first part of this answer -- the part above the horizontal rule. `:)`

Comment: I meant: the youtube tuto is about the phone app Pic-collage, while I use the Windows program Picture Collage Maker Pro. Confusing names :(

Comment: Oh `:)` m'kay `:)` apologies.