# How can I add a line at the center of multiple images at the same time?

Tags: book

I have 30 JPG files which need to be printed as a book. Each JPG file contains 2 pages (left page and right page). I'd like to quickly browse these images and see where the middle line will show up once they're printed. How can I add a line at the center of multiple images at the same time? I'm open to use any program.

E.g. in Photoshop 23.5.1, one can [use](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/158919/11980) `View` -> `Guide` -> `New Guide`:

[image]

[image]

But in this case I'd like the images to have the lines themselves, not just  the Photoshop view.