# How can I display the same guide to all my images opened in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, guides

I have several images opened in Photoshop 23.5.1 on Windows 10. I [used](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/158919/11980) `View` -> `Guide` -> `New Guide`:

[image]

[image]

How can I display this same guide to all my images currently opened in Photoshop, and not just 1 image?

Comment: You could record an Action to place the guide.  Maybe set up a function key to call the Action.