# How can I set some default parameters when creating a new guide in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, guides

In Photoshop 23.5.1 on Windows 10, when [using](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/158919/11980) `View` -> `Guide` -> `New Guide`, the default parameters are:

[image]

Instead, I'd like:

[image]

How can I set some default parameters in the guide in Photoshop?

Comment: An action with an F key shortcut would allow for 1 tap middle guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Guide Layout function instead of the common New Guide

[image]

Comment: Thanks, because of the preset?

Comment: If you set the preset everything will be there each time you create it. In your case you could just add a 1 column, that will go at 50% of your canvas.

Comment: Got it, thanks!